# Broyden's Method mismatched dimensions

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Compute the first two iterates $\mathbf{x}^{(1)}$, $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}$ using Broyden's Method for the initial point $\mathbf{x}^{(0)}=(1,4)$ and the function $f(x_{1},x_{2})=3x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2-x_1x_2$ with $D_0=I$.

Does this question even make sense? To my understanding in this case we need two equations as input. I.e. $f(x)$ be a system of equations $f_1(x_1,x_2)$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2)$. Otherwise applying the method we end up getting a vector equal to a scalar.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but is difficult. Where is this from?

Comment: "The Mathematics of Nonlinear Programming", A.L. Peressini et al.

Comment: Does your book discuss a rank-1 matrix and the Sherman-Morrison formula, as those are key to this algorithm and answer?

Comment: I actually just got an email from the instructor clarifying that we're supposed to take the gradient of the function.

Comment: Of course, that is quite necessary, but my comment 'also' stands. Does your book include the two items I mention?